# Create Customer Group using soap api v2

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I want to create customer group via soap API. but I can't find any documentation regarding this.http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/customer/customer.create.html

even does't mansion about.is there any way to do that .using soap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default magento provide only customerGroupList method.

**You need to create your own API to create customer group for that read**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html

and

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-api-in-magento-part-one--cms-23785

Comment: @srinath madusanka you can upvote as well